# How to limit access to a controller using Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")

Tags: authorize

I created an MVC 5 application which uses Active Directory Authentication.

How can I limit access to my controller only to selected users. I know I can do this `[Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")]` but I don't know if this will work with AD authentication as well. Does '**Alice & Bob**' need to be on the database?

Thank you

Ceci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my little knowledge in this, I understand this objects (Alice,Bob) need to be in Session, this mean, after they authenticate sucessfully in the app will access to the controller, So the Database is not reference but the Session is.

Comment: So I need to set something like this **Session["allowedUsers"] = "Alice, Bob"** somewhere in the Global.asax? Or does automatically know when you do [Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")]

Comment: with just  [Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")] you should be fine.

Comment: I haven't fully tested yet but it looks like its working so far. Thank you. Another related question, How can I redirect a user with a "You are not authorized" message? Right now it just redirects them to the login page if they are not on the list.

Comment: Well, these type of messages I don't use yet but probably you must add a custom error page to your web.config with the codeError 401.2. Please don't forget after make the tests mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: Your answer worked for the first question. Thank you!